# What is a Tourist Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word™/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+phrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Word%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Tourist Word™.

Use the examples below to find the rule.

| Tourist Words™ | Not Tourist Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| LITTLE | SMALL |
| REMOVE | ERASE |
| NOTHING | SOMETHING |
| VARIOUS | ASSORTED |
| OTHER | ALTERNATIVE |
| READ | SCAN |
| ROPE | CABLE |
| LIBRARY | REPOSITORY |

CSV Version:

```
Tourist Words™,Not Tourist Words™
LITTLE,SMALL
REMOVE,ERASE
NOTHING,SOMETHING
VARIOUS,ASSORTED
OTHER,ALTERNATIVE
READ,SCAN
ROPE,CABLE
LIBRARY,REPOSITORY
```

These are not the only examples of Tourist Words™, many more exist.

> Note: Instead of providing hints, I will just add one more example of Tourist/Non Tourist words each day this puzzle remains unsolved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think those are...

> **Words that appear in [Puzzle.SE's Tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour)**

Why?

> Because of their name, and because my trusty Find feature says they all appear there (e.g. 'library' is in the intro, 'rope' is in an example in 'Improve posts' etc.) and none of the Not-Tourist Words do.